# Extract substring before dot

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

I try to substract the first string before a `dot` (`.`) in bash.

For instance:

```
1.2.3 -> 1
11.4.1 -> 11
```

I used the following command based on the [docs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
s=4.5.0
echo "${s%.*}"
```

But it ouptuts `4.5` instead of `4`. I don't get it.

Why is that?

Comment: `echo "${s%%.*}"`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to use `%%` to remove the *longest* match from the end:

```
$ echo "${s%%.*}"
4
```

From [the docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02):

> `${parameter%%word}`
>       **Remove Largest Suffix Pattern**. The *word* shall be expanded to produce a pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter, with the largest portion of the suffix matched by the pattern deleted.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `bash` [Regular Expressions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns) feature built-in in the recent versions of the shell (since `bash 3.0`), using the tilde(`=~`) operator.

```
$ string="s=4.5.0"
$ [[ $string =~ =([[:alnum:]]+).(.*) ]] && printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
4
$ string="s=32.5.0"
$ [[ $string =~ =([[:alnum:]]+).(.*) ]] && printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
32
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use [cut](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html)

```
s=4.5.0
echo $s | cut -d '.' -f 1
```